# How can you configure TypeScript to avoid: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"desc" | "asc" | undefined'.ts(2322)?

Tags: typescript

I tried this simple code with TypeScript:

```
  interface ListFavoritesParameters {
    orderBy?: string
    directionStr?: 'desc' | 'asc' | undefined
    startAfter?: DocumentSnapshot
    endBefore?: DocumentSnapshot
  }

  const listFavoritesDefaultParameters = {
    orderBy: 'updated',
    directionStr: 'desc'
  }

  const listFavorites = async (params: ListFavoritesParameters = listFavoritesDefaultParameters) => {
    // ...
  }
```

Then:

```
params: ListFavoritesParameters = listFavoritesDefaultParameters
```

Is underlined with red by VS Code, with the error message on mouseover:

```
Type '{ orderBy: string; directionStr: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ListFavoritesParameters'.
  Types of property 'directionStr' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"desc" | "asc" | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

in order to get it working I changed the default parameters declaration by:

```
const listFavoritesDefaultParameters = {
    orderBy: 'updated',
    directionStr: 'desc' as "desc" | "asc" | undefined
  }
```

This seems to be really strange. Is there something that can be done to avoid that situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare an object literal with a string property, that property will be typed as a `string`:

```
const listFavoritesDefaultParameters = {
  orderBy: 'updated',
  directionStr: 'desc'
}
```

results in

```
// Intellisense type info:
const listFavoritesDefaultParameters: {
    orderBy: string;
    directionStr: string;
}
```

To avoid automatic type widening, you can declare the `'desc'` `as const`:

```
const listFavoritesDefaultParameters = {
  orderBy: 'updated',
  directionStr: 'desc' as const
}
```

For old TS versions which don't support `as const`, you can also use `'desc' as 'desc'` instead.